# How to prove a random variable only takes strictly positive values?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I tried to prove a random variable only takes values on strictly positive real numbers $\mathbb{R}^+$ by the following

$$P(X>0)=1$$

However, then I realized that $P(X\geq 0)=P(X>0)$. Thus by saying $P(X>0)=1$ cannot eliminate the possibility that $X=0$.

Thus I am a bit confused on how to prove a random variable only takes values on $R^+$, where zero has to be avoid?

**Update:**

I feel that I could try to impose condition such that $P(X\geq a)=1$ were $a>0$. For example take $a=\frac{1}{n}$. This seems the only way to guarantee $X$ cannot take value $0$.

Comment: What is the definition of your random variable $X$ ?

Comment: Random variables which differ only on a null set can be safely identified as the same (in most cases)

Comment: $X:=\sum_{1\leq I<j\leq N}(1+w_{ij}(x_i-x_j)$ where $w_{ij}$ are i.i.d. standard gaussian. Thus it is the summation of gaussian independent non-identical variables $\mathcal{N}(x_i-x_j,(x_i-x_j)^2)$. I proved that the probability $P(X>0)=1-\exp(-\frac{ (\sum x_i-x_j)^2 }{2 \sum (x_i-x_j)^2})$ tends to 1 when $N\rightarrow\infty$. However, I don't know how to eliminate the case $X=0$. In my case, I would need $X$ to be strictly positive.

Comment: @AndrewZhang Yes, If I understood correctly, you meant $P(X\geq 0)=P(X>0)$. But in my case, I would need $X>0$.

Comment: It's not clear why you need $X$ to be positive, and why $X$ positive almost surely is not good enough. In any case, you can always define $\tilde X$ with the same law, and $\tilde X(\omega)>0$ for all $\omega$.

Comment: @AndrewZhang In the context of what I am doing is that $X$ represents a directional derivative of a function at a point, I need to show that the derivative is strictly positive, so that to guarantee that this point is not stationary point of the function. If $X=0$, then my goal is not reached, since this cannot eliminate the case that the point is stationary point.

Comment: If $\mathbb{P}(X>0)=1$, then for any practical purpose you can say that $X$ take only positive values as a random variable.